# Simultaneous overriding and overloading in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, overriding, overload-resolution

Hello everyone I am puzzled about the following piece of C++ code in which overloading and overriding are somehow simulataneous.

Here are the errors that my compiler gives (mingw32-g++ inside Code::Blocks 13.12)

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::show()'
note:  candidate is:
note:  void Derived::show(int)
note:  candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Here is the code that produces them.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Base{
    public:
      void show(int x){
        cout<<"Method show in base class."<<endl;
      }
      void show(){
        cout<<"Overloaded method show in base class."<<endl;
      }
    };

    class Derived:public Base{
    public:
      void show(int x){
        cout<<"Method show in derived class."<<endl;
      }
    };

    int main(){
      Derived d;
      d.show();
    }
```

I tried to declare Base::show() as virtual. Then I tried the same with Base::show(int). Doesn't work either.

Comment: Look up "hiding rule".      Your compiler is doing what it is required to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is name hiding. `Derived::show` hides the methods with the same name in `Base`. You can introduce them by `using`.

```
class Derived:public Base{
public:
  using Base::show;
  void show(int x){
    cout<<"Method show in derived class."<<endl;
  }
};
```